# How to use the FaceTime Live Photos on tvOS?

Tags: photos, appletv, screen-capture, facetime

Using FaceTime on iOS and iPadOS, there's a circular white button that takes a still frame of the video:

[image: iPhone screen of a FaceTime call of a cat and a plush]

It doesn't seem to be available while on a call directly on the TV :

[image: Preview of a FaceTime call on tvOS]

Is there a way to take FaceTime Live Photos directly on tvOS / AppleTV ?